# Perl unpack and newline character

Tags: perl, unpack

I am using the unpack function to convert the contents of a binary file to hexadecimal.

I am doing it as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input=$ARGV[0];

open(INPUT,'<',$input) || die("Couldn't open the file, $input with error: $!\n");
my $value=<INPUT>;
$value=unpack("H*",$value);

print $value,"\n";
```

This prints the contents of the binary input file as a hex string.

However, the issue is that, while parsing the contents of the binary file, if it comes across the byte 0xa (newline character), unpack function stops at that point.

As a result of this, I get the incomplete output in $value variable.

Few examples:

```
65 2E 0D 0D 0A 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BA DC 95 DC FE BD

FE FF FF FF 07 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 0C 00
```

All the content after the byte, 0xa is not parsed by unpack.

So, is there a way to use unpack for the complete binary file so that it does not stop parsing once it encounters a new line character?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution myself. I need to enable the slurp mode before reading the file. local $/ does it :)

Comment: Neon Flash: you can add that as your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

What do you think

```
my $value = <INPUT>;
```

does? Read a line, which is to say read until 0A. Fix:

```
my $value;
{ local $/; $value = <INPUT>; }
```

Also, you want to add

```
binmode(INPUT);
```

after the `open`.